# /etc/init.d permissions issue

Tags: permissions, security, init-script

We are trying to harden our Linux Redhat 5 servers and one of the findings is for the `/etc/init.d`.  The security finding is requiring that we `chmod` it to *700* or more restrictive.  Please see the detail below.

> incorrect permissions=rwxr-xr-x (0755)
>
> directory=/etc/init.d -> /etc/rc.d/init.d

What's the best way to resolve this issue?  I am aware that I can `chmod 700 /etc/init.d` but that reverses for some reason.

Comment: Also, as per @derobert pointed out, there won't be much of additional security. You can refer to here for some more details. http://serverfault.com/questions/49239/what-are-the-correct-permissions-for-etc-init-d-scripts

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the permissions on the link itself; that's typically always 0777. Instead, you can change it on the directory pointed to (which would be `/etc/rc.d/init.d`).

(Honestly, I doubt you're getting much additional security here.)

Answer (score 1):

Files in `/etc/rc.d/init.d` are provided by the distribution. Although they may occasionally be edited locally, this is quite rare. The list and version of the files can easily be reconstructed from other clues, and the content of the files can be retrieved from the operating system vendor. It is not a security issue for this directory to be publicly readable.

If your auditor is finding this kind of non-issue, fire them and get a better one.